# dropzone.js and field parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js

I'm trying to add a really simple drag-n-drop input on my form. Form processing is done by the platform I'm using so that's not an issue. The upload itself works relatively OK and the image preview shows up, but when I submit the form, the image is nowhere in the POST. Also, I need to POST that image with specific parameters. Can anyone shed some light, please? Here's what I have:

```
<form name="cart_quantity" action="MY_URL_HERE" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" maxlength="6" size="4" />
<input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" /> <br />
<input type="radio" name="id[3]" value="7" id="attrib-3-7" /><label for="attrib-3-7">16 Inch Square</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="id[3]" value="8" id="attrib-3-8" /><label for="attrib-3-8">20 Inch Square ( +$5.00 )</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="id[3]" value="9" id="attrib-3-9" /><label for="attrib-3-9">25 Inch Square ( +$10.00 )</label>

<input type="radio" name="id[1]" value="1" id="attrib-1-1" /><label for="attrib-1-1">100% Cotton Broad Cloth 3.5 oz</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="id[1]" value="2" id="attrib-1-2" /><label for="attrib-1-2">100% Cotton Broad Cloth 4.5 oz (little heavier) ( +$5.00 )</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="id[1]" value="3" id="attrib-1-3" /><label for="attrib-1-3">100% Organic Cotton Knit ( +$3.00 )</label><br />

<h4 class="optionName back"><label class="attribsUploads" for="attrib-4-0">Upload Your Image</label></h4>

<div id="my-dropzone" class="dropzone">
    <div class="fallback">
    <input type="file" name="id[txt_4]"  id="attrib-4-0" /><br />
    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="upload_1" value="4" />
<input type="hidden" name="txt_upload_1" />
```

and this is my JS file:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#my-dropzone").dropzone({
        maxFiles: 2000,
        url: "/localhost/",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
        addRemoveLinks: true
    });
})
```

I don't want to submit using AJAX, I just want to be able to select one image using drag and drop (or click). If I leave out URL from my JS, I get an error...

So, the question is - what am I doing wrong here and how can I get the POST to look like:

> name="id[txt_4]"; filename="bck1.jpg"

when I drag-n-drop an image named bck1.jpg?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the `paramName` option to `id[txt_4]` and the `renameFilename` to a function what return the name you want, and you can see more options on [dropzonejs.com](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration)